# PHP PDO class programming:Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to the class programming in php ,Here is my database class.

```
class Database
{
    private $_connection;
    private static $_instance; //The single instance
    private $_host = 'localhost';
    private $_username = 'root';
    private $_password = '';
    private $_database = 'admission_portal';

    //connect to database
    public function connectDb()
    {
        try {
            $this->_connection  = new \PDO("mysql:host=$this->_host;dbname=$this->_database", $this->_username, $this->_password);
            /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
            echo 'Connected to database';
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    //run the query
    public function run($sql)
    {
        $result=$this->_connection->prepare($sql);
        return $result->execute();
    }
}
```

I am extending this to core class to do some database operations.

```
class Core extends Database 
{

    //get all the universities
    public function getData()
    {

        Database::connectDb();
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `adm_universities`';  
        $r=Database::run($sql);
        print_r($r->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));

    }
}
```

Now i am invoking getData function like this way.

```
 $db=new Core();
 $db->getData();
```

But i will get this

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean.
>   What is the error in my code?please help me

Comment: You have a nice sample snippet on how to code a PDO connection class under http://lampload.com/simple-database-connection-class-with-pdo.html

Comment: how could you call the connectDb using scope resolution operator(::) which is used for static method and variable?
i think that part is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the `$result` only in the `run()` method:

```
public function run($sql)
    {
        $result=$this->_connection->prepare($sql);
        $result->execute();
        return $result;
    }
```

Returning the `$result->execute();` is returning `true` because the `execute()` succeeded. You need to return the current state of `$result`.

See if that works.